# Custom Event Tag not firing in GTM

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4, custom-events

Completely new to GTM and having trouble getting ecommerce conversion tracking to work on GA4. This is what debug mode looks like in GTM the tag doesn't fire. Does anyone know what could be causing the issue?

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Have research all the possible reasons, checked the source code, spoken with the developer who added the GTM container to the site, reviewed the tag itself but still none the wiser.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the trigger is waiting for a datalayer event : `add_to_cart`.

So you need to ask the developer to push a datalayer event with ecommerce item when user successfully perform an `add_to_cart` event.

Here is the detail about all ecommerce event and its datalayer.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/ecommerce?client_type=gtm

You have done half of the job. The there is still another part need to be done.

---

Add: I saw you asked a following question on StackOverflow. But I think I should still add it in here.

Here is a concept image shows the process of the tracking

[image]

The green part is you already done.
Set up the Google Tag Manager to GA4, waiting for datalayer from developer.

So the question now :

A. Is your developer implemented the Datalayer code? If yes, can you find someone to verify it?
B. Or your developer didn't get the concept of the Datalayer code. Why it should be implement and when the code need to be triggered.

Comment: Hi Darrell, thanks so much for your response. Does this apply if i'm looking to do: add_to_cart|purchase|remove_from_cart|view_cart|begin_checkout|add_payment_info|add_shipping_info|View_item|view_item_list|select_item ?

Comment: Yes it is for all the events. The part of GTM is like you told GTM if user doing something then help you pass the data to GA4. But you still need developer to told GTM like when is the user really doing something. Because GTM won't know it itself

Comment: Thanks for your responses, is this something i could do myself, would I need to do a dataLayer.push ?

Comment: It is only recommend to let the developer to produce the datalayer. Since the datalayer only can work perfectly if it can give the accurate information at the right timing. If the datalayer itself has the risk to give the wrong data. We will not very convinced the report in GA4 eventually.

Comment: So unfortunately still have had no luck. I sent the following purchase code for the developer to install: 

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/ecommerce?client_type=gtm#make_a_purchase_or_issue_a_refund

 and said to change the variables but still not firing. In the meantime, a Google rep set up two separate tags: Add to Cart and Purchase which has confused me even more. Not sure what the issue is now.

Comment: You can add something about the datalayer which your developer installed. Try to perform an add_to_cart on your website and check the datalayer is showing as expected.